# SAP BusinessObjects RESTful Web Service SDK User Guide for Web Intelligence and the BI Semantic Layer

Tags: business-objects

I am trying to refresh a document that has date prompts in it like Report Begin Date and Report End Date in it and in my XML request I am specifying below but I get error for this:

> 400 Bad Request

Any suggestions ? Thanks in advance.

XML request:

```xml
<parameters>
  <parameter dpId="DP9" type="prompt" optional="false">
    <id>1</id>      
    <answer constrained="false" type="dateTime">           
      <values>                 
        <value>2017-01-01T00:00.000+01:00</value>             
      </values>         
    </answer>     
  </parameter>     
  <parameter dpId="DP9" type="prompt" optional="false">
    <id>2</id>
    <answer constrained="false" type="dateTime">
      <values>                 
        <value>2017-11-01T00:00.000+01:00</value>             
      </values>         
    </answer>     
  </parameter> 
</parameters>
```

Answer (score 0):

I *think* the date values should be specified like:

```
<value>2017-01-01T00:00.000Z</value>

<value>2017-11-01T00:00.000Z</value>
```